# Connection string with an SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I'm trying to establish a connection with a database in a Windows CE 5.0 application and I'm using the Compact Framework 2.0

The database is located inside the project's folder:

C:\Documents and Settings\softdil\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Datalogic\Datalogic

These are the lines I'm using in order to connect and open the database:

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = Datalogic.sdf;";
conn.Open();
```

Which gives me a beautiful "database file not found" error message.

I also tried with the absolute uri with same results:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = C:\\Documents and Settings\\softdil\\My Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\Datalogic\\Datalogic;";
```

What am I doing wrong here?

May be it has something to do with the aplication being debugged (executed) in the mobile device?

I don't really think so because the database works when the application is loaded, meaning that is associated with a listbox and loads data correctly from the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Win CE application we use the following to get the full path of the executing file:

```
string StartupPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
```

Using `StartupPath` you can then add your database name to that path and add it to the connection string:

```
string datalogicFilePath = Path.Combine(StartupPath, "Datalogic.sdf");
string connectionString = string.Format("DataSource={0}", datalogicFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make it work for WinCE, I don't think you have a `C:\\Documents and Settings\\` on your target.

> I don't really think so because the database works when ...

Look in your App.Config, maybe you already have a connectionstring?

Comment: Do I have an app.config if I did not created it manually? I do not see it in my solution explorer.

Comment: No, I forgot but CE does not use them. Still, in your question you say you have data, so what/where is the problem?

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to connect to the database in my computer but it was searching in the Windows CE terminal and that's why it wasn't found. Anyway it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it, in case anyone happens to get the same problem.

When you execute an application in visual studio into a Windows CE terminal device, the application is copied there and also the database. So the connection string must use an uri related to the terminal and not relative to a path in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Give Path of DB File in Data Source property and add providerName in App.Config file

```
<add name="Keyname" connectionString="Data Source=DBPath\Database1.sdf" providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
```